# Maven looking for atifact in wrong repo

Tags: java, xml, maven, maven-3, pom.xml

The project is looking for a dependency otj-pg-embedded from maven central. However, it it fails with the error

```
Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.2 in central (https://loyalty.jfrog.io/loyalty/plugins-release)
```

The pom.xml file looks like this

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.loyalty.finance</groupId>
<artifactId>fin-trx-event-consumer</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>fin-trx-event-consumer</name>
<description>Finance Consumer</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>

    <com.amazonaws.kinesis.version>1.11.438</com.amazonaws.kinesis.version>
    <spock.version>1.1-groovy-2.4</spock.version>
    <groovy.version>2.4.12</groovy.version>
    <consumer.client.library>5.1.0</consumer.client.library>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opentable.components</groupId>
        <artifactId>otj-pg-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kinesis</artifactId>
        <version>${com.amazonaws.kinesis.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.416</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.196</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${spock.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>${groovy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.loyalty</groupId>
        <artifactId>consumer-client-library</artifactId>
        <version>${consumer.client.library}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.15</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/BaseSpec.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <AWS_CBOR_DISABLE>1</AWS_CBOR_DISABLE>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- ToDO exclude junit test when we are running integration test -->
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <!--<groups>com.loyalty.finance.kinesis.client.junit.UnitTest</groups> -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <useConfigFile>true</useConfigFile>
                <registryUrl>https://277983268692.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com</registryUrl>
                <imageName>277983268692.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/${project.name}</imageName>
                <baseImage>277983268692.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/docker-slim-java</baseImage>
                <entryPoint>["/usr/local/bin/get-rds-certs", "/usr/local/bin/kms-env-java", "/startApp.sh"]</entryPoint>
                <imageTags>
                    <imageTag>${build.number}</imageTag>
                </imageTags>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/scripts</directory>
                        <include>startApp.sh</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

and the settings.xml looks like this

```
<settings
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

<servers>
  <server>
    <username>travis</username>
    <!--encrypt these passwords in future-->
    <password>AP39AmWxccbqrCzW118Abj2qwY6</password>
    <id>central</id>
  </server>
  <server>
    <username>travis</username>
    <!--encrypt these passwords in future-->
    <password>AP39AmWxccbqrCzW118Abj2qwY6</password>
    <id>snapshots</id>
  </server>
</servers>
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>libs-release</name>
        <url>https://loyalty.jfrog.io/loyalty/libs-release</url>
      </repository>
      <repository>
        <snapshots/>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>libs-snapshot</name>
        <url>https://loyalty.jfrog.io/loyalty/libs-snapshot</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>plugins-release</name>
        <url>https://loyalty.jfrog.io/loyalty/plugins-release</url>
      </pluginRepository>
      <pluginRepository>
        <snapshots/>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>plugins-release</name>
        <url>https://loyalty.jfrog.io/loyalty/plugins-release</url>
      </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <id>artifactory</id>
  </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
  <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

It looks for that artifact in the place defined in settings.xml. how do i change that. And I need the settings.xml since there are dependencies coming from jfrog, which are defined in the settings.xml

I even tried the force update -U, which doesn't work
mvn -U clean package -s settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your `settings.xml` overrides the location for MavenCentral by using the `central` id.

If you don't want that, use a different id in the `settings.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you override the Url to the central maven repository.
Try to change the id in:

```
<pluginRepository>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>plugins-release</name>
    <url>https://loyalty.jfrog.io/loyalty/plugins-release</url>
  </pluginRepository>
```

The same for the `repository`